# Vee Validate 3 validate at least one item inside v-for required rule

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have Vee Validate 3 set up in my project and I'm trying to validate whether a particular element has been checked within a `v-for` loop. I have several `v-for`s within `v-for`s so am trying to find something that works well for all of them.

I've wrapped my `input` within a `validation-provider` component that exists inside of my loop, but the `required` rule seems to be applied on each and every element, and I need to simply check whether at least one has been checked with my `v-model`.

Here's my markup:

```html
<validation-observer v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
  <form @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit(submitForm)">

    <!-- Step 1 -->
    <validation-observer v-if="editor.step == 1" :key="1">
      // inputs
    </validation-observer>

    <!-- Step 2: Choose Sources -->
    <validation-observer v-if="editor.step == 2" :key="2">
      <ul v-for="(source, table, sourceIndex) in editor.sources" :key="sourceIndex" class="mb-3">
        <li>

          <!-- Data Source (Table) -->
          <validation-provider
            name="data source"
            :rules="{ required: { allowFalse: false } }"
            v-slot="{ errors, classes }"
          >
            <label :for="'source-'+sourceIndex" class="font-medium text-gray-700 cursor-pointer block p-4 border rounded-md">
              <div class="flex">
                <div class="flex-1">
                  <p class="text-xs font-medium text-gray-400">Data Source</p>
                  <h5 class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-500" :class="source.isChecked ? 'text-indigo-600' : ''">{{ table }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div v-if="source.isChecked" class="flex-1 items-center flex justify-end" :class="source.isChecked ? 'text-indigo-600' : ''">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <input :id="'source-'+sourceIndex" v-model="source.isChecked" type="checkbox" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded cursor-pointer hidden">
            </label>
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </validation-provider>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </validation-observer>

  </form>
</validation-observer>
```

Right now, the `required` rule is listening for whether I've checked all of the elements inside of my loop, I just need to check whether at least one has been selected, why isn't this working?